# Best way to implement ICard building Application in Java

Tags: java, image, swing

haveI had implemented a Java Swing Based application that builds ICard based on the input from user. An ICard can be printed and saved as jpg format on local disk. ICard has a specific GUI pattern based on name,photo,address etc.

I had been implementing it by settings user entries along with other data in Swing Components, in case of text or image inputs like Name, Address, Photo  etc I set them on JLabels. Then while printing it take a snapshot of Parent component containing all data and then on print command saving the snapshot of component on local system folder and then printing that jpg. Now there are cases where name, address and other information got quite big on number of characters and then my hole parent layout got disturb and distort as well. I had used GridBagLayout for creating ICard.

Please provide your suggestion as I think this is not the best way to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could set a Maximum amount of chars, so your layout is not disturbed. But that's bad. You could add Scrolling when the text is bigger than the component. But then printing will need some hands-on to see all the data ... you may want to print not a snapshot but some "Print-View".

Comment: Thanks @Fildor for your comments yes you are right on Print-View i had been trying it but the ICards needs to be saved as JPG's too. Although i put parent container on Scroll View but parent component size will be set to something size constraints are there if i ignore size constraints your idea is good will implement it putting parent component in scroll view.